# Correct pattern for ZeroMQ Server/Client type

Tags: c#, zeromq, netmq

I have a server that needs to get instructions to run processes for clients on another machine.

The clients send a job message, the Server processes the job and later sends the back results.

I tried using the NetMQ Request-Response pattern (see below)

This works nicely for 1 client, BUT if a second client sends a request before previous client job is finished - I get an error.

I really need to be able to receive ad-hoc messages from clients, and send results when they are completed. Clearly, I am using the wrong pattern, but reading the ZeroMQ docs has not highlighted a more appropriate one.

```
namespace Utils.ServerMQ
{
    class ServerMQ
    {
        public static void Go()
        {
            using (var responseSocket = new ResponseSocket("@tcp://*:393"))
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Server waiting");
                    var message = responseSocket.ReceiveFrameString();

                    Console.WriteLine("Server Received '{0}'", message);

                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                    {
                        RunProcMatrix(message, responseSocket);
                    });

                }
            }
        }

        public static void RunProcMatrix(object state, ResponseSocket responseSocket)
        {
            var process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = Path.Combine(@"H:\Projects\Matrix\Matrix\bin\Debug\", "Matrix001.exe"),
                    Arguments = (string)state,
                    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
                    CreateNoWindow = false
                }
            };
            process.Start();
            process.WaitForExit();


            responseSocket.SendFrame((string)state);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a ROUTER socket on the server side, so it can receive multiple requests at a time. ([Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-REQ-to-ROUTER-Combination)) REQ sockets on the client side are still fine unless the server may arbitrarily push data to them, then they need to be DEALER sockets.

Note that for sockets beyond REQ/RESP you need to manually handle the message envelope (the first frame of the message indicating its destination). [Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#The-Request-Reply-Mechanisms)

<sub>The 0MQ docs are incredibly dense... I don't blame you for not intuiting this from them :)</sub>

This example from the NetMQ docs is full ROUTER-DEALER: https://netmq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/router-dealer/#router-dealer, you can take just the router side and it should work the same though.

Comment: Thanks - is there an example of this combination? A simple one!

Comment: @ManInMoon Added the sample from the docs. Unfortunately this part of the learning curve of 0MQ is really steep.

Comment: I just switched my ResponseSocket above to Router socket and code run without changes BUT I receive lots of empty messages!

Comment: @ManInMoon That's because you are seeing the message envelope. You have to adapt your read code to handle it (RESP sockets strip the envelope before handing off to the user)

Comment: I can read the message in routerSocket now - but HasOut is false - therefore I can't send message to client

Comment: @ManInMoon No idea what "HasOut" is, sorry. Router sockets can definitely send responses the same way RESP can.

Comment: @ManInMoon Sending responses from ROUTER, if you are still having trouble with that, is probably a good separate question. Double check the example I linked though.

Comment: Got it sorted now - didn't expect to have to fiddle with so much - but help was much appreciated